Power supply for microcontroller
Can a microcontroller rated for 5-7V be powered by bipolar supply of +/-(2.5-3.5)V
Considering fact voltage values are only relative scale and only absolute difference matters?
A specific part number for microcontroller  may be much used ATmega328P,most of the specification mention 7-12V as power input,can it be operated with +/-(3.5-6)V
Edit-1: This is followup to a question i already posted ,As the part numbers I asked about in previous question were pretty old,didn't got much responses,So i thought rephrasing the question might get me some more responses
NE567 supply voltage
Edit-2:wrongly mention the atmega power supply spec as 7-12V correcting it to 5.5V max.can it be powered by +/-2.75V.
Edit-3:
The comments and answers suggest I am not conveying my question properly ,so I will explain my thought process, to read bipolar signal with uC it need to be level shifted and AC coupled,if it is really  slow varying needs a larger coupling capacitor for AC coupling,in that case the uC can be programmed with 5.5V power,then under operation it can be switched to +/-2.5V to read negative voltages without DC bias and  coupling capacitor

With such little detail given, this is just a question on voltage arithmetic. If an answer on power supplies for an MCU in a specific application is wanted, please edit your question (don't post new info in comments) and add a considerable amount of detail and practical relevant information about those.

ATmega328p cannot operate from a 7-12v supply - the absolute maximum rating is 6.0v, with a typical range of 1.8v to 5.5v (with associated speed derating at lower voltages)... you are likely thinking of a board with an integrated regulator (e.g: Arduino)

dhuwarkesh - It appears you may be misusing this site. Your comment below (and question update) suggest that you actually want to get more replies on your question about the NE567, but you posted a new question "in context of microcontrollers just to get more response". The problem is that the answers can be different, depending on the circuit around each device. Getting an answer when it's an MCU (with that full circuit) may not apply to an NE567 (with that full circuit). || If you wanted more response to your previous question, the [help] gives this advice.

@SamGibson sorry didn't do it intentionally,because microcontroller use is wide spread I thought I will get a chance to interact with more people,should I remove the link of the already asked question?

@dhuwarkesh - Thanks for replying. "should I remove the link of the already asked question?" No, as that may appear to be hiding the real reason for this question. || The best option IMHO was probably not to ask this question in the first place, but instead to focus on what you said you really want to understand with the NE567, by improving that question. However, now you have asked this question, and it has an answer, I'm not keen (at the moment) to delete it all.

No, because the ATMega328P MCU is not rated for 5V to 7V supply to begin with.
It is rated for 5.5V max, and it does not have to work outside nominal range of 5.5V, and absolute max rating where it starts to damage permanently is only 6V.
If you read 5V to 12V, you must be reading specs of some PCB board which has the Atmega328P and some voltage regulators on the PCB.
What the MCU just needs is a 5V voltage over it. It does not matter if it is a +/- 2.5V bipolar supply to some 0V reference, or 1000V and 1005V supply to some 0V reference, or maybe even 5V differetial riding on a 320VAC 50 Hz sine wave to some 0V reference (which will result if you just rectify the mains or use a capacitive dropper, but it will be dangerous to use another reference that other tools use.

If that is the case can it powered with +/-2.5V

Yes but it will also work with 2.5V, albeit a bit slower.

@dhuwarkesh Can it be done vs should it be done... Powering a microcontroller with anything than 5V or 3.3V would be sheer madness, I'm afraid. Most components are assuming one of these two industry standards. If you have a pure analog board then that's another story, but then you wouldn't use some AVR anyway.

@Lundin as I mentioned my original question was about analog component NE567,link is given in question,only rephrased the question in context of microcontrollers just to get more response.

@dhuwarkesh Keeping the MCU supply sound and stable to an industry standard has a lot of advantages - for example you may be able to debug it and program it using conventional tools instead of inventing those yourself.

@lundin as you said i agree it is best to maintain standard, i want get clarified conceptually

Microcontrollers are not like OP amps. They have a single power supply of 3.3 or 5V and a GND.  Some MCUs have a maximum power supply tolerance of about 10%. Its better to consult the documentation of the MCU or contact an application engineer of the manufacturer of your MCU. Any voltage over that limit would cause damage to the MCU.
